# How to share data with child classes

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I need to be able to access a parent (not super) class from child classes.

In my case the data structure becomes exactly 3 levels deep:

**Class A contains an array with x * Class B containing an array with y * Class C.**

instances of Class C need to be able to access properties from Class A.

My idea was to pass down a callback, that would return the needed values.
I can **not** pass down static values from class A, since they can change over runtime.

Is this the proper way of handling the data flow between my instances, or can this be achieved in a more elegant way?

I set up a fiddle for this case (for the sake of simplicity only 2 levels deep): https://jsfiddle.net/2chngzqg/

```
class A {
    constructor() {
        this.foo = "bar";
    }

    shareProps = () => {
      return this.foo;
    }

    createSubClass() {
      this.sub = new B(this.shareProps);
    }
}

class B {
    constructor(callback) {
      this.logShared = callback;
    }
}

const a = new A();

a.createSubClass();
console.log(a.sub.logShared())

a.foo = 'baz';
console.log(a.sub.logShared())
```

Comment: I don't mean to throw this off track but if classes need to share data maybe they shouldn't be separate. I only bring this up because without more information It's hard to answer the actual question. You are asking how to do Y but it seems you got to Y while trying to solve X. Information from X would be helpful here to get a good answer.

Comment: isn't it a common use case to have classes that have array of subclasses?

Comment: I don't know if it's common. What is the use case? What are you trying to solve?

Comment: The classes represent my data model for a shopping system. It has a **cart**, **products** and product **options**. The options and products sometimes depend on information that is being stored in the cart

Comment: I see. I don't think, in this case, that any of these things are subclasses of another. Instead, they are just data associated with one another. A cart has a list of products which may have a list of options. What situation comes up that requires product options to know about whats in the cart?

Comment: because the cart holds information about active discounts, delivery conditions and so on

Comment: I know we are speaking in pretty abstract terms right now but should the products return their price and then the cart massages the price as necessary to meet the cart requirements instead of the product trying to fetch those requirements and ingest them? I don't think it's necessary for the products to know about all the outside influences that could affect the end price. The product class cares about the product and the price it's listed at. Bulk discounts, shipping costs and even linked product discounts might be handled better at a different level than the individual product.

Comment: maybe you are right. Generally technically speaking: How would you make classes share Information on an instance level so that class B know to which instance A it belongs? Symbols?

Comment: Yes, passing callbacks is fine. But there's an even simpler option: just pass the parent instance itself.

Comment: @Bergi would that be a problem performance wise if I pass down the whole instance if I have a lot of products in my cart?

Comment: @ManuSchiller No. Objects are reference values - it doesn't pass a copy of the contents of the object.

Comment: @ManuSchiller Generally, I would keep the information requirements separate.  I'm glad someone was able to get you a working example but I would watch out when doing lots of work in a product option that requires knowledge about the cart. IMHO that is backwards. Same for products knowing about the cart. Maybe decorator classes made by the cart would work better? `products.push(DiscountedProduct(.10, Product))`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about that?.. In case the already mentioned `Cart` type contains a list of `Product` types and each `product` does list its `Option` types, and as seen from the example, each type is in control of how to create and/or add other depended types to it's list, then ... just provide this information about the hosting type to the constructor/factory function of the hosted type, thus every `option` features a `product` slot/property and every `product` features a `cart` slot/property.

The [changed code of the OP's provided fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2chngzqg/2/) then might look like that ...

```js
class Foo {
    constructor(host) {
    this.foo = "foo";
    this.host = host;
  }
  createMember(Member) {
    return (this.member = new Member(this));
  }
}

class Bar {
    constructor(host) {
    this.bar = "bar";
    this.host = host;
  }
  createMember(Member) {
    return (this.member = new Member(this));
  }
}

class Baz {
    constructor(host) {
    this.baz = "baz";
    this.host = host;
  }
  createMember(Member) {
    return (this.member = new Member(this));
  }
}

var foo = (new Foo);

console.log('foo : ', foo);
console.log('foo.foo : ', foo.foo);
console.log('foo.member : ', foo.member);
console.log('foo.host : ', foo.host);

var bar = foo.createMember(Bar);

console.log('bar : ', bar);
console.log('bar.bar : ', bar.bar);
console.log('bar.member : ', bar.member);
console.log('bar.host : ', bar.host);
console.log('bar.host.host : ', bar.host.host);

var baz = bar.createMember(Baz);

console.log('baz : ', baz);
console.log('baz.baz : ', baz.baz);
console.log('baz.member : ', baz.member);
console.log('baz.host : ', baz.host);
console.log('baz.host.host : ', baz.host.host);
console.log('baz.host.host.host : ', baz.host.host.host);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score -1):

Although not es6 - you can achieve this using functional inheritance.

Using the Object `that` to hold the class properties. In this example `B` is instantiated onto the scope of `A`.

```
const A =  ()  => {
  let that = {}      

  // Public variable
  that.foo = 'bar';

  // Public function
  that.shareProps = () => (that.foo);

  // Subclass functions attached to this classes scope
  that.createSubClass = () => {
    that = B(that);
  }

  return that;
}

const B = (that) => {

  that.logShared = () => (that.shareProps());

    return that;
}

const a = A();
a.createSubClass();
console.log(a.logShared())
a.foo = 'baz';
console.log(a.logShared())
```

The 'sub classes' can be attached onto other public variables within the function if needs be.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2chngzqg/)

This is more flexible when you inherit from the 'parent' class in the 'child' classes because you always have access to whatever functions and variables are added to `that`.

```
const A =  ()  => {
    let that = {}

  that.foo = 'bar';

  that.shareProps = () => (that.foo);

  return that;
}

const B = () => {
  // A is inherited 
  let that = A();

  that.logShared = () => (that.shareProps());

    return that;
}

const C = () => {
  // B is inherited 
  let that = B();

  return that;
}

const c = C();
// Calls the function in B() => that.logShared()
console.log(c.logShared())
// Changes the value in A() => that.foo
c.foo = 'baz';
console.log(c.logShared())
```

See [here](http://therealmofcode.com/posts/2012/11/functional-inheritance-javascript.html) for more examples of functional inheritance.

Comment: No. OP is not looking for any form of inheritance (although his choice of words is certainly confusing)